# Mockito testing events

Tags: mockito

I have a class which generates events e.g.

```
public class EventSource{
 public addEventListener(EventListener listener).....
 public raiseEvent(){
    Event e=....
    listener.handle(e);

 }

}
```

I'm using Mockito to mock an EventListener and want to do an equality on the event object (e.g. event.getTime()..event.getMessage() etc). The event object doesnt have an equals method so I cant easily create another object and do an assert.

Whats the normal way of doing this with Mockito?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want to use an [argument captor](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#15).

For example:

```
ArgumentCaptor<Event> argument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Event.class);
verify(mockedListener).handle(argument.capture());
assertEquals("ExpectedMessage", argument.getValue().getMessage());
```