# Unit test which verifies only a few elements

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

There is an interface:

```
interface IEventListener
{
  void onEvent(List <IEvent> events);
}
```

There is an event class:

```
class EventB
{
  private final int id;
  private final A a;
  private final String somethingElse;
...
// constructors, getters
...
}
```

And there is a class to test:

```
class Doer
{
 IEventListener eventListener;
 void doSomething(Aaa a)
 {
   eventListener.onEvent(Arrays.asList(new EventA(1), new EventC(2)));
...
   eventListener.onEvent(Arrays.asList(new EventB(42, a.getA(), "foo"), new EventA(3), new EventB(0, a.getA(), "bar")));
...
   eventListener.onEvent(Arrays.asList(new EventC(4)));
 }
}
```

The `Doer` is a code which I need to test, the method `doSomething` produces packs of events, and I need to test if it produces a particular event in some specific conditions.

More precisely I want to have a unit test which calls the method `doSomething` and checks that EventB is sent with "42" and `A` as from method argument `a`. All other events should be ignored.

To make such test I've only came up with solution involving quite verbose code with ArgumentCaptor, for-blocks, and magic boolean flags...

What is the best way to make a unit test for it? Maybe the code design is bad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The design is correct, this is how you test it with Mockito:

```
import org.hamcrest.Matchers;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
public void firesEventsOnDoSomething() {
  Listener listener = Mockito.mock(Listener.class);
  Doer doer = new Doer(listener);
  doer.doSomething(aaa);
  Mockito.verify(listener).onEvent(
    Mockito.argThat(
      Matchers.hasItem(
        Matchers.allOf(
          Matchers.instanceOf(EventB.class),
          Matchers.hasProperty("a", Matchers.equalTo(aaa.getA())),
          // whatever you want
        )
      )
    )
  );
}
```

It's Mockito 1.9.0 and Hamcrest-library 1.2.1.

To use JUnit 4.10 together with Hamcrest-library 1.2.1 you should use `junit:junit-dep:4.10` artifact, and exclude `org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core` from it:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit-dep</artifactId>
  <version>4.10</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
      <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
  <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
  <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
  <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.9.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
      <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks. It looks very promising. However, as I see it requires that `onEvent` is called with a list which contains the event. But as you see in my code snippet the `onEvent` is called several times and only once it has the desired event. Any ideas how to improve it?

Comment: Also hamcrest doesn't work with junit 4.10: `NoSuchMethodError: org.hamcrest.core.AllOf.allOf(Lorg/hamcrest/Matcher;Lorg/hamcrest/Matcher;Lorg/hamcrest/Matcher;)Lorg/hamcrest/Matcher;`

Comment: I think that it will work exactly as you need. Mockito will verify that at an execution with require argument happened. All other executions will be ignored, as long as the required one is in place. See my updated answer for mockito+junit+hamcrest combination.

Comment: btw, it is not required to use `<exclusion>` because the `hamcrest-core` artifact dependency is explicitly included above.

Comment: If you avoid `<exclusion>` element the order of dependencies will matter. It means that `hamcrest-core` will have to stay always above `junit-dep`, which is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JUnit4 you can try a paremetrized test. Here there is an example http://www.mkyong.com/unittest/junit-4-tutorial-6-parameterized-test/.

If for each of your parameters you have to compare with a different result, you should better consider them as different test cases.

Comment: The `Doer` is a code which I need to test, the method `doSomething` just produces packs of events, and I need to test if it produces a particular event in some specific conditions. Your answer is unrelated.

Comment: If the problem is to mock the event, you could follow this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9905928/mockito-testing-events

Comment: Yes, I know about `ArgumentCaptor`, but maybe there is a better way, the link you sent has a simple case when only single event is sent. I have packs...

Answer (score 0):

Create dummy implementation of `EventListener`:

```
class DummyEventListener implements EventListener {
    private int expectedId;
    DummyEventListener(int expectedId) {
       this.expectedId = expectedId;
    }
    void onEvent(List <IEvent> events) {
        for (IEvent event : events) {
            if (!(event instanceof EventB)) {
                continue;
            }
            EventB eb = (EventB)event;
            assertEquals(expectedId, eb.getId());
            // add more asserts here
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can use one of available java mockup frameworks: 
EasyMock, JMock, Mockito, JMockit etc.

Comment: I use Mockito. How to do it with Mockito? (Or I can switch to any other framework if necessary). BTW, your code doesn't check that such event exists at all. Need much more code... it makes unit test look awful..